# Transition logo only when it slides left not when it goes back to original position

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm building my homepage with a custom theme in wordpress. 
I placed my logo in the middle of the page and I need it goes fixed when I scroll to it. I achieved it with this code:

```
    var stickyLogo = jQuery('.logo_centered').offset().top;
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {  
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > stickyLogo) {
        jQuery('.logo_centered').addClass('fixato');
    }
    else {
        jQuery('.logo_centered').removeClass('fixato');
    }  
});
```

and it works.

I also added a transition when click on it to hide it and open the slidein menu.

```
jQuery('.logo_centered').on('click', function(){
   jQuery('.logo_centered').toggleClass('hideme') 
})
```

While this is the menu opening

```
jQuery('.centrato').on('click', function(){
   jQuery('.overlay').toggleClass('overlay--active') 

})
jQuery('.overlay').on('click', function(){
  if(jQuery('.overlay').hasClass('overlay--active')){
    jQuery('.overlay').removeClass('overlay--active')
  }
})
jQuery('.overlay').on('click', function(){
     jQuery('.logo_centered').toggleClass('pushme');
})
jQuery('.overlay').on('click', function(){
  if(jQuery('.logo_centered').hasClass('hideme')){
    jQuery('.logo_centered').removeClass('hideme')
    jQuery('.logo_centered').removeClass('pushme')
  }
})
```

But, as you can see on my demo website:
http://arioldigioielleria.it/test/

the animation is triggered also when it goes fixed and back. 
How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the transition when scrolling by making your transition specific to horizontal movement:

```
.logo_centered {
    transition:left 0.5s;
}
```

By the way, this is now possible using only CSS with `position:sticky`. You might find it more maintainable than JavaScript:

> A stickily positioned element is treated as relatively positioned until it crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is treated as fixed until it reaches the boundary of its parent.

-[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but do you mean switiching its absolute position or its fixed position? I mean, the problem is how can I put it in the same position with a sticky position? (I'm newbie at coding and this work is not mine, I'm only doing some edits). Thank you

Comment: Just tried with `.fixato {
    transition:0s;
}` but it stills doing it, when I scroll to top but at least no more when I scroll down.